# Let $a >b$ positive numbers. Find the minimum value of $\tfrac{a!+1}{b!+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Let $a >b$ be positive numbers. Find the minimum value of $$\dfrac{a!+1}{b!+1}$$

My try to solve the question:

I take $b=a-1$ to solve question so $$\dfrac{a!+1}{(a-1)!+1}=\dfrac{a}{(a-1)!+1}+\dfrac{1}{(a-1)!+1}$$
That's all. How can I get a solution? Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: What are you minimising over? Is it over $a \in \Bbb{N}$ for fixed $b$? Over $b \in \Bbb{N}$ for fixed $a$? Or over both $a, b \in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: I think $a,b$ over natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

*HINT* let's recall $f(n) = \dfrac{(n+1)! + 1}{n! + 1}$.

Note that $f(n + 1) > f(n)$ for any $n$. Also note that $\dfrac{(n+k + 1)! + 1}{n! + 1} \ge f(n)$ for any $k \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

How $a > b$ then $a! > b!$. Soon, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\dfrac{(a+n)! + 1 }{b! + 1}> \dfrac{a! + 1}{b! + 1} > 1. 
$$

Comment: Using this I don't think can be found min value of it because if  $n$ be increased then nominator increase. İs it possible to more detail user253963?